# how to document Windows server (ISP,location, address ,etc)

Tags: windows-server-2008

I had to take over the server maintenance, and my first job is documenting the servers especially the ISP, could you guys give me the best practices and guidelines for this task?

And could you suggest a propper way of communicating whit the servers? Right now I have a remote desktop connection with them. Most servers are Windows Server Standard and Window Web Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here: http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Document_your_Network

You need to document (in short):

- Non-Network Information (vendors,authorizers,purpose statement)
- Network Globals
- Network Infrastructure
- Devices
- Peripherals
- Software
- Administrative
- SLA
- Diagrams

Answer (score 1):

A basic CMDb ([Configuration Management Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMDB)) should contain at least:

1. Technical information:

   - Each network interface (IP address, subnet mask, gateway and an uplink/ISP/switchlayer reference)
   - Details about it's software, roles and responsibilities
   - Any special configuration needs (for easier disaster recovery)*
   - Passwords (stored in encrypted fields, and not too easily accessible)
2. Ownership information:

   - Who owns and ultimately decides the fate of the server
   - Who has the technical responsibility
   - Licensing information
3. Relationships:

   - References to directly linked network appliance (what switch is it connected to?)
   - Network Diagrams
   - Physical Locations
   - Authentication Hub (Active Directory/RADIUS server/token service/Local SAM)

---

*(*) Get in the habit of thinking in, and describing, best practices for configuring servers and network equipment (and stick to them). That way, all you need to document on a per-server basis is any **deviation** from these standards*